# Any other service like CUPS-pdf for Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, printing

I recently installed CUPS-pdf to export files to PDF in Lubuntu. However it seems that CUPS only exports blank PDF file. Is there any other service like CUPS that exports files to PDF file for Lubuntu?

Comment: The gutenprint printer driver includes a print to file option that creates pdf.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've already installed gutenprint driver with CUPS. Even if I select the 'Print to File' option,  it creates a blank PDF file. Any other idea?